# MongoDB best practices- getting collections

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I am new to Mongo, and was wondering what best practices would be in terms of accessing collections. Best way to explain is through sudo code:

```
public class DBManager {
    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private DBCollection collection;

    public DBManager() {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient( "127.0.0.1", 27017);
        collection = mongoClient.getDB( "DB" ).getCollection("collection");
    }

    public String add(String item) {
        if(collection!= null) {
            ObjectId id = new ObjectId();

            BasicDBObject insert= new BasicDBObject("_id", id)
                .append("item", item)
            collection.insert(insertRepo);
            return id.toHexString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean remove(String id) {
        if(collection!= null) {
            ObjectId id = new ObjectId(id);

            DBObject dbObject = collection.findOne(objectId);
            collection.remove(dbObject);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not really clear on what happens behind the scenes when you do "getCollection". Is it good practice to just do it once when you initialize, or should i be just setting up the MongoClient in the constructor and then getting the collection for each request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's fine to do it in the constructor. It's even better to define the `DBManager` as a `singleton`, so that the collection is initialized during boot-strap